# cannot change prop in flatlist renderItem

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to render array DATA using two way: **Normal View** and **FlatList**. What I learnt, we pass `props` in **map** and **renderItem**.

First block gives correct output:

```
const DATA = [
    {id: '1',title: 'First Item'},
    {id: '2',title: 'Second Item'},
]

const list = DATA.map((lst)=>{
    return(<Text key={lst.id}>{lst.title}</Text>)
})

const Home=()=>{
  return (<View><Text>{list}</Text></View>)
}
export default Home
```

In following `FlatList` Component, it throws error:

```
TypeError:TypeError:undefined is not an object(evaluating 'lst.title')
```

If I change `lst` to `Item`, then it shows correct output. Is `item` a predefined keyword in renderItem? If I change `item` to any other words, it throw error.

```
const DATA = [
    {id: '1',title: 'First Item'},
    {id: '2',title: 'Second Item'},
] 
const Itm=({title})=>{
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Home=()=>{
  return (
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={({lst}) => <Itm title={lst.title} />}
        keyExtractor={itm => itm.id}
      />
  );
}
export default Home
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that in your `renderItem` you are destructuring your object reading the `lst` keyword:

```
renderItem={({lst}) => <Itm title={lst.title} />} //Wrong
```

You are trying to read property `lst` in an object that doesn't have that key.

change `({lst})` to `(lst)`:

```
renderItem={(lst) => <Itm title={lst.title} />}
```

You can read about object destructuring in:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

EDIT.

Looking at the `FlatList react-native`  [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#renderitem), `Flatlist` returns an object looking like :

```
{item, index, separators}
```

Where `item` is the item you need want to render.

So you need to either use :

```
renderItem={({item }) => <Itm title={lst.title} />} //must be item
```

or

```
renderItem={({item: lst}) => <Itm title={lst.title} />}
```

Comment: I got surprised, output is blank according to correct way mentioned in your answer. But it shows correct output if I change `lst` to item in wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the  {}

```
renderItem={({lst}) => <Itm title={lst.title} />}
```

it does not need to write it know it destructor he is object  try to used this shape

```
    renderItem={(lst) => <Itm title={lst.title} />}
```